# Lift-json extract json with 'type' field into a case class

Tags: scala, lift-json

I am trying to extract JSON into a case class using lift-json. Here is my case class:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

Here is the json

```
{ "name": "Some Name", "age": 24, type: "Student" }
```

How can I extract the `type` field into an instance `Person`?

```
json.extract[Person]
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? Have you tried it with: `case class Person(name: String, age: Int, \`type\`: String)`. Obviously `type` is a reserved word in Scala, but you can work around that with back-ticks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Backticks allow you to use reserved names.

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int, `type`:String)
```